# Product of position eigenvectors at different times

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, quantum-interpretations, commutator, eigenvalue

I've been thinking about this, and it might sound like a stupid question, but I can't seem to find an answer anywhere, here goes:

Whenever we calculate expecation-values between two position eigenvectors taken **at different times** we need to apply the time-evolution operator $\hat{U}(t_b,t_a)$ to get the position-vectors at the same time.

So in stead of saying that:

$\langle x_b,t_b|x_a,t_a\rangle=\delta(x_b-x_a)$,

we say that:
$\langle x_b,t_b|x_a,t_a\rangle=\langle x_b|\hat{U}(t_b,t_a)|x_a\rangle$.

Is this because of the fact that generally the position operator $\hat{x}$ doesn't commute with the generator of the time-evolution $\hat{H}$?

Or said otherwise, is this because of the fact that according to Heisenberg's equation of motion that we have (in the Heisenberg-image of course) that:

$i\hbar\dot{\hat{x}}=[\hat{x},\hat{H}]\neq0$ in general.

If we would have $[\hat{x},\hat{H}]=0$ then we would have that

$\langle x_b,t_b|x_a,t_a\rangle=U(t_b,t_a)\langle x_b|x_a\rangle=U(t_b,t_a)\delta(x_b-x_a)$, right?

> Extra explanation on the last formula (@joshphysics):
>
> I denote an operator with a hat and the eigenvalues without hats, so in my last formula I basically took the operator $\hat{U}(t_b,t_a)$ and took it's eigenvalue by letting it work on the ket $|x_a\rangle$ which gives me the eigenvalue $U(t_b,t_a)$. Which looks weird since an time-independant base yields a time-dependant factor this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sake of completeness, let's first unravel some definitions and prove the identity
\begin{align}
  \langle x_b, t_b|x_a, t_a\rangle = \langle x_b|\hat U(t_b,t_a)|x_a\rangle.
\end{align}
The definition of each position eigenstate $|x\rangle$ is that it's a normalized eigenvector of the position operator $\hat x$ corresponding to eigenvalue $x$;
\begin{align}
  \hat x |x\rangle = x|x\rangle.
\end{align}
Given a time interval $t$, time evolution operator for that interval is given by an operator exponential;
\begin{align}
  \hat U(t) = e^{-i\hat tH/\hbar}.
\end{align}
We can use the time-evolution operator to define a time-evolved (aka heisenberg picture) position operator;
\begin{align}
  \hat x(t) = \hat U(t)^\dagger \hat x \hat U(t).
\end{align}
Then, the states $|x,t\rangle$ are defined as the normalized eigenstates of the operator $\hat x(t)$ corresponding to eigenvalue $x$;
\begin{align}
  \hat x(t) |x,t\rangle = x|x,t\rangle.
\end{align}
But notice that
\begin{align}
  \hat x(t) \big[\hat U(t)^\dagger |x\rangle\big]
  &= \hat U(t)^\dagger\hat x\hat U(t)\hat U(t)^\dagger |x\rangle \\
  &= \hat U(t)^\dagger \hat x |x\rangle \\
  &= \hat U(t)^\dagger x|x\rangle \\
  &= x\big[\hat U(t)^\dagger |x\rangle\big]
\end{align}
which implies that
\begin{align}
  \hat U(t)^\dagger|x\rangle = |x,t\rangle.
\end{align}
It follows that
\begin{align}
  \langle x_b,t_b|x_a,t_a\rangle
  &= \langle x_b|\hat U(t_b)\hat U(t_a)^\dagger|x_a\rangle \\
  &= \langle x_b|\hat U(t_b)U(-t_a)|x_a\rangle\\
  &= \langle x_b| \hat U(t_b-t_a)|x_a\rangle.
\end{align}
This is exactly what we wanted to prove if we simply note the conventional definition
\begin{align}
  \hat U(t_b,t_a) = \hat U(t_b-t_a).
\end{align}
Now let's address your question

> Is this because of the fact that generally the position operator $\hat x$ doesn't commute with the generator of the time-evolution $\hat H$?

Basically, yes.  Notice that if it did commute, then $\hat x$ would also commute with $U(t)$ and $U(t)^\dagger$, so we would have
\begin{align}
  \hat x(t) = \hat U(t)^\dagger \hat x \hat U(t) = \hat x \hat U(t)^\dagger \hat U(t) = \hat x
\end{align}
in which case the eigenstates of $\hat x$ and $\hat x(t)$ can be chosen equal.  In particular, the inner products between them would be the same;
\begin{align}
  \langle x_b, t_b|x_a, t_a\rangle = \langle x_b| x_a\rangle
\end{align}
Notice, in particular, that your last equation is incorrect.  You could have seen this immediately in fact because you are equating an inner product to an operator.

**Addendum.** As you remark in your comment below, your intention was for the symbol $U(t_b,t_a)$ to denote a complex number.  In that case, your last expression is correct. However, when $\hat U$ commutes with $\hat x$ and we have $\hat x(t) = \hat x$, we can simply choose normalizations such that $|x,t\rangle = |x\rangle$ for all $t$, in which case we would have $U(t_b,t_a) = 1$.

Comment: maybe I should have clarified my last equation a bit more (see edit). But it did indeed look weird to me in the sence that $U(t_b,t_a)$ is a time-dependant factor while I'd expect the product to be time-independant. Thanks for the great answer, I should have known that the time should be added by definition.

Comment: @Nick Ah I see yeah then your expression is fine.  See the addendum.